# Класс для работы с crontab

Tags: php

Добрый день #ХэшКод. Ищу рабочий php класс с crontab: добавление, удаление, вывод заданий. Все права есть (выделенный сервер).

Comment: Я думаю, что там быстрее написать.

Comment: @jsalert, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: KoVadim, Пробовал разные классы: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1153 и еще пару -- не работает.

Comment: vi - вот лучший инструмент для изменений crontab-ов.

Comment: vi - да, это отличный инструмент.

@jsalert там подробно все описано. Может просто сесть и написать свой?

А вот фраза "не работает" - это не ответ программиста. Программист выкладывает логи, вывод с ошибками (но не своими грамматическими:) ).

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/MediovskiTechnology/php-crontab-manager

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

[Источник](https://www.google.ru/search?q=php+crontab+editor)